# Laravel select form default value

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, array-merge

I'm having problem on setting the default value of "Please Select" on my select form from laravel. here comes the code.

```
$user = \App\User::where('role_id','=','3')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->lists('name','staff_id');
```

and here's on my blade

```
{!! Form::select('requestby', $user, Input::old('requestby'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

i have tried to put the `array_merge` but it seems like it is overwriting the `<option>` value from staff_id to index value. what should i do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_merge` will re-index the array when merging. You can use `+` for this -

```
$user = array('' => 'Please Select') + $user;
```

The `index`s will not be changed.